# Tensorflow js Error: Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense4 to have shape [,10], but got array with shape [4898, 2]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to multi inputs with multi outputs at tensorflow-js.
Software is working with multi inputs and one output but erroring with multi outputs.

```
`function createModel() {
    const model = tf.sequential(); 
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [11], units: 50, useBias: true, activation: 'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 30, useBias: true, activation: 'tanh'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 20, useBias: true, activation: 'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10, useBias: true, activation: 'softmax'}));
    return model;
}
function prepareData(data) {
  
  return tf.tidy(() => {
    tf.util.shuffle(data);

const inputs = extractInputs(data);
const outputs = data.map(d => [d.quality, d.alcohol]);


const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, inputs[0].length]);
// here code below working with one output
//const outputTensor = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(outputs, 'int32'), 10);
const outputTensor = tf.tensor2d(outputs, [outputs.length, outputs[0].length]);





const inputMax = inputTensor.max();
const inputMin = inputTensor.min();  
const outputMax = outputTensor.max();
const outputMin = outputTensor.min();

const normalizedInputs = inputTensor.sub(inputMin).div(inputMax.sub(inputMin));
const normalizedoutputs = outputTensor.sub(outputMin).div(outputMax.sub(outputMin));

return {
  inputs: normalizedInputs,
  outputs: normalizedoutputs,
  inputMax,
  inputMin,
  outputMax,
  outputMin,
}
```

});
}
`

I am trying to work with an ai at node js somehow layers not working with multi outputs.